# The glass door on my convection oven broke. Can I still use it?

Tags: microwave, convection, glass

I have a KitchenAid microwave + convection oven combination. I was cooking a pie (350F), and this happened:

[image]

The inner glass shattered; the outer glass and all other parts seem fine. I'm getting a warranty replacement, but in the meantime...

Hypothetically, is there any reason I couldn't continue using the microwave, convection oven, or both?

Comment: I would use it but I would not recommend you use it.

Comment: Just wondering how the replacement has been working? And where do get a new glass piece. Exact same thing happened for my microwave

Comment: @Silver Ours was replaced under warranty; we've used it several times since with no apparent issues.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use the microwave - since you can't be sure which pane of glass is microwave-reflective.

And I'd be concerned about that glass shards working their way loose with thermal stress and falling into the food.

Comment: Normally there's a wire mesh to block the microwaves, rather than a coated glass.

Answer (score 1):

I would not. I'm cautious like that. Had the second pane not been there, it looks like the glass would be all over your floor, spewing radiation. What if a second glass burst happens? You won't have a glass guard to keep it from spewing.

A regular convection oven or a microwave oven can be purchased for under $50. if you need one for Thanksgiving. But, if you can get by without them until you buy a replacement for the failed one, then wait and replace it when you can.

Comment: The glass was held in by itself; the second pane was uninvolved. Looks like it's some variation of safety glass.

Comment: Maybe it has a metal latticework in it to prevent the glass from moving, but also to work as the metal radiation guard. Still, I wouldn't use it.